# Symfony Lexik Translation Bundle Error (apc_exists)

Tags: php, symfony

I am getting the error:

> Attempted to call function "apc_exists" from namespace
>   "Lexik\Bundle\TranslationBundle\Translation"

I've reinstalled the OS and installed my standard LAMP stack and cloned project from repo.

I'm running my project on PHP7 based web server on Elementary OS.
I've used  http://lornajane.net/posts/2016/php-7-0-and-5-6-on-ubuntu this tutorial to setup 2 different php versions, because i need php5.6 for other of my projects.

Could this problem be with Lexik? Or maybe, php? Is it possible I failed to install some php modules?

Comment: Made title more searchable, moved the exact error to the body of the question. Cleaned up some general grammer errors and made the question a little bit easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the fact that you don't have APC extension.

Since, this is `PHP7` on `Ubuntu`, you should probably be able to run something like this:

```
apt-cache search apcu
```

There should be something like `php7.0-apcu` or similar to that. After that, it is just a matter of installing it like any other package (via `apt-get`)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer . After trying to install this extension - i have next response from CLI.  `Note, selecting 'php-apcu' instead of 'php7.0-apcu'
php-apcu is already the newest version (5.1.7+4.0.11-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.` So, it means, that i already has this extension....

Comment: @ICS_Vortex Check if it's also installed for the PHP of your webserver (which can be different than the CLI one)

Comment: @Veve You mean, check if this module is enabled? I just found that `APCu Debugging` is disabled, from my `phpinfo()`.

Comment: @ICS_Vortex Try running `php -m` from command line. That will should you installed modules of `php`. However, you web server might be using different `php.ini`..

Comment: @JovanPerovic apc and apcu are installed.